# jQuery Click event is not fired at all

Tags: plugins, widgets

I'm trying to make a widget plugin that allows user to upload image. but I have a problem in jQuery events that it is never happen !

**includes/myplugin.scripts**

```php
function media_uploader_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_register_script('media-uploader', plugins_url().'/simple-plugin/js/main.js',array('jquery'),null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('media-uploader');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'media_uploader_enqueue');
```

**js/main.js**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log($('#xyz')); // works !

    $('#xyz').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("in click event");  // never happens !!
    })

})
```

Comment: This seems like it's specifically a jquery question about how to fire your jquery event, so as it's not related to Wordpress it might do better on a Web Development stackexchange, or StackOverflow. If you leave the question here you might want to add the HTML of the xyz element too

Comment: I found the answer and I think this is related to wordpress, thought, thanks for your suggestion @mozboz

Answer (score 2):

I Found the answer for my question , And I'm sharing it here in case anyone interested.

the problem was that click event won't work on dynamically generated html elements

and the alternative that worked is using on

```js
$('body').on('click','#elementID',Callback)
```